# Python Function for Year, Month, Date & return Day

Tags: python-3.7

I have written following Python Function which should return Day, when year, month & date is provided to function. For Testing, I have limit it to 3 years & then call the function using print. But it always return “Saturday”. What’s wrong in function.

```
enter code here
def dayOfYear(y,m,d):
    if y in [2018,2019,2020]:
        if m in [1,2,3]:
            if d in [31,28,1]:
                return('Saturday')
            else:
                return('Thursday')
        else:
            return('Sunday')
    else:
        return(None)

print(dayOfYear(2018,1,31))
print(dayOfYear(2019,2,28))
print(dayOfYear(2020,3,1))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  will give you a good good guide on how to ask questions.  Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will show what the comunity considers a good question.  Its a great start but nowere in this code is Saturday...

Comment: Your program is working as expected. All test cases result in 'Saturday'.

Comment: Hi @JohnnyMopp  It should return Saturday, Thursday & Sunday instead of just Saturday

Comment: For all 3 test cases, all 3 `if` statements are true so 'Saturday' is returned. To get a different result change your test cases. For example: `2018,1,31` and `2019,2,2` and `2020,4,1`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp After Changing the cases as per your  direction i.e. 
        print(dayOfYear2(2018,1,31))
        print(dayOfYear2(2019,2,2))
        print(dayOfYear2(2020,4,1))                                                                             
  Still getting Same result i.e. Saturday. I think IF statement needs some Fixing

Comment: @Shahzad https://ideone.com/GFWNMM

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That one is Better. But I want is that it should return me the Day against my given Year, Month & Date, not any other value. So even with yor provided solution, if I call function with my given year, month & Date, it still return Saturday.

Comment: I have got expected result with 3 separate IF statements but Nested IF failed

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  https://ideone.com/PmRjhH
Check this Solution.
But Nested IF failed. Is there any way to fix it